# yesod persistent postgresql complex record

Tags: database, haskell, orm, yesod, persistent

I am using persistent to save the following records (Time is UTCTime).

```
type Price = Int
type Volume = Int

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateBook"] 
  [persistLowerCase|
    Level
      limit     Price
      volumes   [Volume]
      deriving Show Read Eq

    Book
      time      Time
      asks      [Level]
      bids      [Level]
      deriving Show Read Eq
  |]
```

When I migrate the structures I get a Book table:

```
CREATE TABLE book
(
 id serial NOT NULL,
 "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 asks character varying NOT NULL,
 bids character varying NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT book_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
 )
```

and a table Level:

```
 CREATE TABLE level
 (
   id serial NOT NULL,
   "limit" double precision NOT NULL,
   volumes character varying NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT level_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
 )
```

When inserting a book, the level table remains empty and the Book table contains an entry containing JSON versions of the intended record.

Questions:

How can I get persistent to use the actual simple types (e.g. int and time) for the columns instead of JSON for the complex types?

Does Persistent know how to store a many to many relation?

e.g. given a record A with a list :: [B], can I get it to create a third table with

```
AId | B
-------
 1  | b1
 1  | b2 etc
```

I am using the following packages:

```
persistent-postgresql-1.0.3
yesod-persistent-1.1.0.1
Postgres 9.1
```

Comment: Persistent does not attempt to manage relations, so you will need to define lookup tables manually. Specify list types such as `[Level]` causes the entire list to be serialized into a single field as you've observed. You can use identifiers such as `BookId` and `LevelId` to refer to records of other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for `[Level]`, storing just the ID allows you to store a simple type in a json list.

```
type Price = Int
type Volume = Int

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateBook"] 
  [persistLowerCase|
    Level
      limit     Price
      volumes   [Volume]
      deriving Show Read Eq

    Book
      time      Time
      asks      [LevelId]
      bids      [LevelId]
      deriving Show Read Eq
  |]
```

Alternatively, if you need to query across the relation, you need to define a "through" or M2M table, just like in a normal relational database design.

```
type Price = Int
type Volume = Int

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateBook"] 
  [persistLowerCase|
    Level
      limit     Price
      volumes   [Volume]
      deriving Show Read Eq

    Book
      time      Time
      deriving Show Read Eq

    BookAsk
      book      BookId
      level     LevelId

    BookBid
      book      BookId
      level     LevelId
  |]
```

As is the case for, for `[Volume]`, the problem is [in persistent-postgresql](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/blob/master/persistent-postgresql/Database/Persist/Postgresql.hs#L247). persistent is hardwired to marshal `PersistList` values as JSON, instead of using postgres's native support for array column types. If you want to fix this, you'll need to submit an issue or a pull request.